# Sql Server Stored Procedure error: "A severe error occurred on the current command. the results if any should be discarded"

Tags: sql, error-handling, return

I am having a sql stored procedure where I check for a validation and  if it fails the validation the Sp stops right here..
For stopping after validation i have used RETURN;

Now while executing a test case for that invalid input i am getting an error as " a severe error occurred on the current command. the results if any should be discarded"
Am sure this was thrown from the RETURN code i use

Anything I needed to do?

Comment: what's your sql code?

Comment: Lots of other answers on this. Basically, patch your SQL Server http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=a%20severe%20error%20occurred%20on%20the%20current%20command.%20the%20results%20if%20any%20should%20be%20discarded

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. The reason was that OUTPUT parameters data types was wrong in my client code.

Comment: I hope this answer helps somebody else, who finded it in search engine